# How to query based on a Date field in the latest version of Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model:

```
var model = {
      created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    , data: { }
}
```

...but I cannot seem to select based on a date as per the guides I'm using.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
Model.find({
    created: { $lte: new Date('2012-03-16T20:54:35.630Z') }
}).run(function(err, models) {
    // ...
});
```

I'm wondering if Mongoose has changed again... or if I'm just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have looks ok. Here is a [working example](https://gist.github.com/2406640).

Are you getting error or just no results?

Another great place to get help is on the official forum [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mongoose-orm).

Comment: Hey +aaronheckmann!  Thanks for the response, I did in fact figure out the issue; it was related to our data.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to ... `.exec(function(err, ...` instead.