# How to create a query on a Date field in MongoDB using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to query a collection in Mongo database, to get all record with `Time` field in a date range. `Time` is defined as Date in database.
My environment: Node.js, Express, Jade, javascript.

This is the javascript code:

```
var query = {};
var timeQuery = {};
timeQuery["$lt"] = new Date().toISOString();
query["Time"] = timeQuery;
console.log(query);
db.model('testruns').find(query).exec(function (err, testruns) {
    console.log(testruns.length);
    // doing something
});
```

the result printed to console:

> { Time: { '$lt': '2014-10-30T15:04:39.256Z' } }
>   0

The query returns 0 results (there should be more)

By the way... Running date queries from RoboMongo returns results, just the wrong ones. for example:

```
db.testruns.find({Time : {"$gte" : new Date("2014-10-30T15:13:37.199Z")}})
```

returns all records.

What I tried:
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973304/mongodb-mongoose-querying-at-a-specific-date), [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249223/mongoose-query-nested-documents-greater-or-less-a-certain-date), [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182680/how-to-query-based-on-a-date-field-in-the-latest-version-of-mongoose), mongoose documentation of course, and many more results from google.

Most of them give the same answer, none of them works for me. HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to a schema definition, not directly to this code. The code of the query was correct. a schema definition had this field(Time) as String, which caused MongoDB to try and find a string in a date field...

Answer (score 0):

as far I see you are not including the field to reference in the query, can you try this:
I assume your field name is 'time'

```
var date = new Date(); //or the date you want to compare
db.model('testruns').find({"Time":{"$lt":date}}).exec(function (err, testruns) {
    console.log(testruns.length);
    // doing something
});
```

Comment: I am, it is in timeQuery parameter. I added a log to the query to show it. Just in case, I tried the exact code you wrote, with no success.

Comment: got you, do you want to get the dates just lower than, the date to compare right?, can you try using the notation I suggested?

Comment: I want to get date range. But before that I need to make ANY time query work (I tried many gt/gte/lt/lte queries)

Comment: can you post your schema?